# Logstash grok match pattern not working even though grok constructor says it is okay

Tags: logstash, grok

I've been building some grok patterns to parse the /var/log/secure log file and everything has been working fine.  I create the grok patterns at http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/ and even then test them at http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ and both sites show the patterns matching perfectly.  I'm using logstash 2.1.1, elasticsearch 2.1.1 and kibana 4.3.1 all running on CentOS 7.1 using JAVA openjdk 1.8.0.65-2.b17.

I have then taken those patterns and implemented them with a filter on my logstash servers.  Most of the filters work fine but SECURENETREG and SECURENETBADGE are not matching for some reason.  logstash --configtest shows no problems and logstash is running normally otherwise, but when I look at entries that should match those patterns in Kibana, it seems that none of the parsing  is working.

Here is my patterns file, /etc/logstash/patterns.d/secure-log.grok:

```
SECURETIMESTAMP %{MONTH}%{SPACE}%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}
SECUREPROG %{PROG:program}(?:\[%{POSINT:pid}\])?
SECUREHOST %{IPORHOST:host}
SECUREBASE %{SECURETIMESTAMP:secure_timestamp}%{SPACE}%{SECUREHOST}%{SPACE}%{SECUREPROG}:
SECURESU %{SECUREBASE} (runuser: |)%{PROG:pam_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:pid}\])? session %{WORD} for user %{USER:user}( by \(uid=%{NUMBER:su_caller_uid}\)|)
SECURESUDORUN %{SECUREBASE}%{SPACE}(%{USER:user} : TTY=%{DATA} ; PWD=%{DATA} ; USER=%{USER:sudo_runas_user} ; COMMAND=%{GREEDYDATA:sudo_command}|\S+:%{SPACE}(TGT verified|error reading keytab %{GREEDYDATA}|authentication %{WORD} for '%{USER:user}'%{GREEDYDATA}|%{GREEDYDATA}user=%{USER:user}))
SECURESSHDPUBKEY %{SECUREBASE} (Found matching RSA key: %{GREEDYDATA:rsa_key}|%{WORD} publickey for %{USER:user} from %{IPORHOST:src_ip}( port %{NUMBER:port} %{WORD}( \[preauth\]|: RSA %{GREEDYDATA:rsa_key}|)|)|)
SECURESSHDREST %{SECUREBASE} (Did not receive identification string from %{IPORHOST:src_ip}|pam_unix\(sshd:session\): session %{WORD} for user %{USER:user}|Starting session: command for %{USER:user} from %{IPORHOST:src_ip}|Connection from %{IPORHOST:src_ip}|Accepted (password|publickey) for %{USER:user} from %{IPORHOST:src_ip}|Received disconnect from %{IPORHOST:src_ip}|Connection closed by %{IPORHOST:src_ip}|User child is on pid %{NUMBER}|Set %{UNIXPATH} to %{NUMBER})
SECURENETREG %{SECUREBASE} connect from %{IPORHOST:src_ip}%{GREEDYDATA}
SECURENETBADGE %{SECUREBASE} (%{WORD:whois_action}|Authentication %{WORD:auth_result}): (reply from %{URI:whois_uri}: Result: %{GREEDYDATA:whois_result}|User: %{USER:user}, %{GREEDYDATA:auth_result_detail}, From: %{IPORHOST:src_ip}, %{GREEDYDATA}, URL: %{URI:netbadge_source_uri})
```

Here is my config file that applies the filter, /etc/logstash/conf.d/46-filter-secure-log.conf:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "secure" {
    grok {
      patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns.d/"]
      match        => { "message" => [
        "%{SECURESU}",
        "%{SECURESUDORUN}",
        "%{SECURESSHDPUBKEY}",
        "%{SECURESSHDREST}",
        "%{SECURENETREG}",
        "%{SECURENETBADGE}"
        ]
      }
      add_field    => {
        "received_at"     => "%{@timestamp}"
        "received_from"   => "%{host}"
      }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "secure_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

And finally here are some (scrubbed of identifying info) log messages that match perfectly in the pattern testers but do not seem to get properly parsed in logstash (though I know the filter is hitting them because I temporarily tested by adding a new field just to make sure the messages were being run through the filter):

```
Jan  8 09:22:22 netbadge-serv netbadge[3534]: verify_whois: reply from https://whois.domain.edu/whois: Result: 0:-1000:0:0:Error with submitted data Illegal characters in data stream#012
Jan  8 09:22:19 netreg-serv autoreg.pl[13867]: connect from 10.250.100.22 (10.250.100.22)
Jan  8 09:22:19 netbadge-serv netbadge[3522]: Authentication success: User: mst3k, Password: Test Test, From: 10.250.28.30, Appid: webmail_login, URL: https://www.mail.domain.edu/switchboard/
Jan  8 09:39:51 netbadge-serv netbadge[11358]: Authentication failure: User: mst3k, Invalid User/Password, From: 10.250.28.31, Appid: Shibboleth Identity Provider, URL: https://shib.domain.edu/idp/Authn/RemoteUser
```

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing due to staring at all this for so long, so I sure hope someone can tell me what's going on here.

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  At the end of SECURESSHDPUBKEY there was an | before the ending ) that was matching everything else so it never got to the patterns further down.  I knew it was simple, had just been staring at that grok too long.